# There any way to insert images inside the code (just for comprehesion) in any IDE compatible with Game Engine Unity3D (Monodevelop for example)?

Tags: unity, geometry, image, ide, monodevelop

**M**y code has a lot of geometry codes, thinks that shouldn't be represented just by comments I don't know if it exists, but should be fine to insert images like png in the middle of codes explaning that math behind, just in case I forget what any classes/method/lines do in future. Thanks.

Comment: TempleOS by Terry Davis is a crazy 64bit real-time OS that happens to allow actual images and 3D models to be included on the source code editor that is included with it. If you are willing to learn his own HolyC language and develop for his platform you can do what you want to do in your question there. Totally don't recommend though.

Comment: @Josh Petrie, Every Game Engine use an IDE as far as I know.

Comment: @JamesB Regardless of whether or not that is true, that doesn't make it on-topic here. You're asking about putting images into code while you write it. That has nothing to do with game development.

Comment: @JoshPetrie coding is part of game development, maybe you should find better things to do.

Comment: Yes it is. But we still don't consider questions that have nothing specifically to do with game development on topic here. I suggest that you ask on another StackExchange site, and also that you find a way to better communicate your ideas - one that does not involve being rude to other members - as it will serve you far better.

Comment: I am not being rude, you asked for it, game development always include an IDE. Or you know other form to program in unity?

Answer (score 3):

Other than ASCII art? No, not that I'm aware of. The closest you could get would be documentation generators like **doxygen** that will create documentation files from comments, which might also include markup for images.

Besides that you could link to images using URLs, which are clickable in most editors and/or use markdown for basic formatting.

Comment: ASCII arte in the middle will not be that good. Hahaha. I will try some other option.